# How do I use gradient image which gradates in both directions as border-image?

Tags: css, linear-gradients, border-image

I want my `<div>` to have a bottom border which starts from a distance away from the left. It's like:

```
abc
  ^^^^^^^^^^
```

where `^` stands for a piece of border.

I achieved this using `border-image`. I set a `border-image` to a `linear-gradient()` image, which starts transparent, and becomes gray from some pixels.

```html
<style>
    div {
        width: 200px;
        border-top-style: none;
        border-bottom-style: solid;
        border-width: 1px;
        border-image: linear-gradient(to right,
            transparent 0,
            transparent 1em,
            lightgray 1em,
            lightgray 100%) 100% 1;
    }
</style>
<div>abc</div>
```

Now the new requirement is to add a 1px white line right below the existing line to mimic a 3d effect. I thought I could simply add a vertical gradient to the border image, but I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of border consider multiple background. I used different colors to better see the result:

```css
.box {
  width: 200px;
  background: 
    linear-gradient(blue, blue) 1em 100%/ 100% 1px no-repeat,
    linear-gradient(red, red)   1em 100%/ 100% 2px no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">abc</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Achive it with `box-shadow`

If you are using `display: flex` to your div you should position pseudo `after` element using `position: absoute`

See this example:

```css
body {
      background-color: lightgreen;
    }
    div { 
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    
    }
    div:after {
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      display: block;
      width: 200px;
      height: 1px;
      box-shadow: 10px 1px 0 0 lightgray, 10px 2px 0 0 white;
    }
```

```html
<div>abc</div>
<div>edf</div>
```

Comment: Works well in simple `display: block` div, but in my case the div is `display: flex`, which makes it follow on the right of last child. I'm trying if I can adapt.

Comment: Hmm It would be better if you mentioned this in question. You can use `absolute` positioning to align it as you want. I'll update the answer

Comment: This will almost work, but the border bleeds out of the div if the div is `width: 200px;`(you removed it in the updated code), though it's not hard to deal with. Based on your code I set `overflow-x: hidden; bottom: 2px;` and got a satisfying result. The `bottom: 2px;` is because without it the line will be invisible due to `overflow-x: hidden;`.

Comment: I've accepted another answer. Your answer works but involves more changes. Thanks for your quick answer!